# Group of automorphisms and finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory, finite-fields

> Prove that the group $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_{p^n}^*)$ has order $\varphi(p^n-1)$.
>   We denote $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}^*$ the multiplicative group of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ and $\varphi$ Euler's arithmotheoretic function.

We know that $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is an extension of the field $\mathbb{F}_p$ with $p^n$ cardinality  and the extension is Galois and $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{p^n}/\mathbb{F}_p)= \langle \sigma \rangle$ where $\sigma$ is the Frobenius automorphism.

Also the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is cyclic.

Can someone help me to combine these facts to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is not always cyclic, for instance $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})$ is elementary abelian of order $4$, as $1^{2} \equiv 3^{2} \equiv 5^{2} \equiv 7^{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$.

Comment: What can i do for the finite field i mentioned..

Comment: The problem is that im not so familiar with group theory!

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: woof, you're right, thanks. Certainly, it's still of order $\phi(n)$, but I was distracted and thought only of the prime case.

Comment: You know that $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_{p^n}^*) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(p^n - 1)\mathbb{Z}$.  What are the automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$?  Note that a map $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is determined by the image of $1$.  What elements of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ generate the group?

Comment: i assume that the elements which are ralatively prime with m generate tha group..

Comment: But why $Aut(F_{p^n}^*) $ is isomorphic to group of integers modulo m?

Comment: thats the part i want to prove

Comment: Whoops, sorry that was a typo: I meant $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}/(p^n - 1)\mathbb{Z}$.  And you are right about the generators.  So taking $m = p^n - 1$, how many elements are relatively prime to $p^n-1$?

Comment: i see ,thank you for your help?

Comment: Great!  If you've figured it out, why not write an answer to your question?

Comment: i will tomorrow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{F}_{q}^*$ is a cyclic group of order $q - 1$ where $q = p^n$. Since any two cyclic groups of equal order are isomorphic, we know that $\mathbb{F}_{q}^* \cong \mathbb{Z}/(q - 1)\mathbb{Z}$.

Now it is not too hard to show that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \cong U(n)$ where $U(n)$ is the group of units under multiplication mod $n$, which when coupled with the statement above, establishes the claim. In order to understand why $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \cong U(n)$, think about the image of a generator of $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ under an automorphism...